# Why are my new Azure end points not working?

Tags: azure

I have two virtual machines (running Ubuntu Linux) hosted on Azure, and I'm trying to set up new endpoints for one of them. I've successfully created the end points but the connections won't go through. I've used tcpdump to verify that the SYN packets are not even reaching the VM. I don't have a firewall configured on the VM either. All my existing end points work fine, and if I delete one of them, it stops receiving connections. I just can't add any new, working endpoints.

So I tried the same with my second VM and everything works as expected there. The only difference between them is that VM #2 has end points 22, 80, 19000, 19001 while the problematic VM #1 has 80, 443, 19000 and 19001.

What could I be possibly doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you run a traceroute from both endpoints to see at what point they terminate? Your initial details seem to point to a routing issue if no packets are arriving at either endpoint from the other.

Answer (score 0):

The situation resolved itself. I received an email telling me that the maintenance period was over and that my server will have been rebooted. After that the new endpoint worked as expected.